# Change date format from database

Tags: stimulsoft

I'm using Stimulsoft Reports.Ultimate 2016.1. My date format from the database is `dd-mm-yyyy`. Is there any way that I can change the format into `dd/mm/yyyy` and display it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by following query. Replace dbDate and table_name with yours.

If dbDate is in varchar format you need to convert it first to datetime and then you can apply the below query.

```
select convert(NVARCHAR,convert(datetime,<dbDate>),101) from <table_name>
```

If dbDate is already in datetime format then you can simply apply below query to format date into dd/mm/yyyy

```
select convert(NVARCHAR,<dbDate>,101) from <table_name>
```

If you have any suggestions or doubt let me know.